# How to make WPF page navigation code look better?

Tags: wpf

I want to make a program by WPF which includes several pages.

I have a `Window` and several `Page`s now.

In order to navigate, I use

```
this.Content = new Page1();
```

in the main window (from `Window` to `Page`), and

```
((Window)this.Parent).Content = new Page1();
```

between pages (from `Page` to `Page`), because `Page` can only be sub-element of `Window` or `Frame`.

However, the second line of code above looks quite ugly.

Is there a better way to achieve the same goal?

<sub>I have coded from several Windows Phone applications before, and I think it might be better to navigate between `Page`s rather than hide/show elements (such as `Grid`s).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If your navigation code is on your Page class, either :

- move it to the window class
- create an event in the Page class, and react to it on the Window class.

Comment: The second way sounds promising. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you can't just put a Frame in your Window ?

You could use NavigationService.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx

http://www.paulstovell.com/wpf-navigation

Maybe this could help:

http://azerdark.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/multi-page-application-in-wpf/

Comment: If I put a `Frame`, I still cannot start a navigation from `Page` to `Page` without writing ugly. In addition, I am already using `NavigationService`. I have just wrote it in another way.